# undefined method `root?' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ancestry

I have some category tree constructed using Ancestry gem for Rails 3
I am able to use all Ancestry methods between console and other controllers. 
But now I am facing problem to use methods like root? and is_root? To determinate if the selected cat is root category.

**My code inside Application controller**

```
private
def set_categories
  def set_ids
    case action_name
    when "index"

   @origin_cat = Category.find_by_name(params[:category])

    if @origin_cat.root?
    @descendant_ids = @origin_cat.descendant_ids
    @descendant_prods = Product.where(:category_id => @descendant_ids  ).paginate(:per_page=>10, :page=> params[:page])
else

    end

......
```

My erorr looks like this :

```
undefined method `root?' for nil:NilClass
```

Comment: do `p params` to see if the key `:category` has any value or not first.

Comment: `Category.find_by_name(params[:category])` came up with no results.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your call to `.root?`; problem is `@origin_cat` is nil because the find failed.  You should check the value of `params[:category]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should first check whether `@origin_cat` is not `nil`, than whether `@origin_cat.root?` is true or not, as following:

```
   @origin_cat = Category.find_by_name(params[:category])

  if @origin_cat && @origin_cat.root?
    @descendant_ids = @origin_cat.descendant_ids
    @descendant_prods = Product.where(:category_id => @descendant_ids  ).paginate(:per_page=>10, :page=> params[:page])
  else

  end
```

or you can just do:

```
  if @origin_cat.try(:root?)
```

With try, even if `@origin_cat` is `nil`, it will just return `nil`, instead of throwing an error.

More details on try [here](http://apidock.com/rails/Object/try).

Answer (score 2):

Your `@origin_cat` is `nil`.Make sure the value of params[:category] is not `nil`

```
if @origin_cat.present? && @origin_cat.root?
    @descendant_ids = @origin_cat.descendant_ids
    @descendant_prods = Product.where(:category_id => @descendant_ids).paginate(:per_page=>10, :page=> params[:page])
else

end
```

Comment: Why would he use `unless` like you do? It has the opposite logical meaning to an `if`, so now that code will only run if it is NOT root. It also does not solve the exception when `@origin_cat` is `nil`. Basically, you change his intention of `if @origin_cat.root?` into `if not @origin_cat.root?`.

Comment: This is still going to give the same error. Also changes OP's logic.

Comment: @KirtiThorat oops Edited!

Comment: @DaniëlKnippers Apologies.Used unless in the wrong situation.Updated.Have a look at it.

Comment: @Pavan Yeah it's better now. I did not actually downvote you but since you fixed it now, +1. I see others have removed their downvote.